# Error trying to connect a firebird database with ODBC or C# application

Tags: c#, odbc, firebird, firebird-3.0

I'm trying to connect my c# application in a Firebird database. Using the user and password I got works on firebird sql tool. But when I go to my c# app, I got an error. 
So I went to the ODBC drivers, trying to connect and I got the same error.
Here is the odbc screen

[image]

And here is the error
[image]

Like I said, it really works with firebird ISQL tool.
I already changed a few configs into the firebird.conf file.
I had to set

```
WireCrypt = Enabled
```

for resolve a previously problem, and now I'm trying this one but without success

```
AuthServer=Srp,Legacy_Auth
```

Any help guys? Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT**

The error in C# application is exactly the same of ODBC.

Stacktrace:

```
   at FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.GdsConnection.Identify(String Database)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateManagedDatabase(FbConnectionString options)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.ClientFactory.CreateDatabase(FbConnectionString options)
   at FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnectionInternal.Connect()
```

FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient
5.11.0.0

Server version

[image]

I`m not referencing fbclient.dll yet!
But I have it after install the Firebird. The version is
3.0.2.32703

Thanks for now!

Comment: Which version of the Firebird ADO.net driver are you using in your C# application, which version of the ODBC driver, and which version of fbclient.dll is it using? Exactly which version of Firebird 3 do you have? Why focus on the ODBC error when your primary problem is with the C# application? Specify exactly which error you get in your C# application (full stacktrace, please).

Comment: Because the error in my C# application is exactly the same of ODBC!

Comment: unrelated: Character Set as "NONE" is very dangerous setting! Set it to some meaningful value like UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by just going to Firebird folder (windows explorer) and changing the security for everyone (full permission to everyone). So my app and odbc started working.
I'm sure it's not the right way but I solved my problem for now.
Waiting for better answers.

Comment: Were you running Firebird server as an application instead of as a service?

Comment: Yes! We will face firebird just once, for import a new customer to our database, so, there was no reason to install as a service if I'll work with it just a few days.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with access to the security database, but then I wonder why isql did work. In any case, if you want/need to run as an application then installing outside program files could be an alternative. Or you could put the security database elsewhere. But if it is just for a few days, you might just want to keep the current situation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for your time man! Yes, I'll keep the situation but for another people with the same problem, I was trying to figure out the reason.

Comment: You're welcome. When I have time, I'll see if I can reproduce it and if I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I suspect he has some misconstructed Connection String, so in general he does not use Firebird Server process but instead runs Firebird Embedded. He did not show his C# code, so it is hard to say, just my gut feelings. This would explain the demand for his client app to FB files access, as his app became a temporary FB server